# Essential singularities of holomorphic functions and a certain limit

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in the punctured unit disc in $\Bbb C$, and suppose $0$ is an essential singularity for $f$. Let $M_{f}(r) = \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$. Prove that
$$\lim_{r \to 0^{+}}r^{n}M_{f}(r)=\infty$$.

for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

So I think the idea is to analyze the Laurent series expansion for $f$, and to use the fact that infinitely many negative powers exist in the expansion. Where do I go from here?

EDIT: Specifically, I am trying to use Cassorati-Weierstrass to find a sequence convergence to 0 in the punctured disc whose image grows as a sequence that blows up faster than r^n shrinks (say, n fixed). I am having trouble formulating this notion.

Comment: Use Cassorati-Weierstrass

Comment: Can you elaborate just a little? This is what I'm trying to nail down.

Comment: Do you know what Cassorati-Weierstrass says?

Comment: Yes, the image of the punctured disc in question is dense in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: So inside the disc of radius $r$ you have values with absolute value greater than $n/r^n$, and $|f(z)| \leq M_f(r)$ at those values.

Comment: I see. So i can take a sequence converging to 0 in the disc, but whose image in absolute value is larger at each step in the sequence than your suggestion.

Comment: exactly, you'll also have to use the maximum modulus principle, restricting yourselve in an annulus excluding the 0, where $f$ is holomorphic. (Because you're asking for the max on $|z| = r$.)

Comment: Can't I just take a value on the boundary of, say, the punctured disc with radius 1/m for each m?

Comment: Sorry, I dont think my Idea is going to work, Im trying to fix It, you see, even if you have big values of $f(z)$ inside the disc you cannot guarantee they're attained (or that they're even bigger) at $|z| = r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll show that if $r^n M_f(r) \not \to \infty$ then the function $z^n f(z)$ can be holomorphically extended at $0$.

Assume that 
$$r^{n}M_{f}(r)\not \to \infty$$

Thus, there exists a constant $C>0$ and a sequence of positive numbers $r_k \to 0$ so that $$r_k^n M_{f}(r_k) \le C$$

Then for the function $g(z) = z^{n} f(z)$  we have 
$$M_g(r_k) \le C $$

Let's note now that if for a holomorphic $g$ on the pointed disk we have 
$M_g(r_k) \le C$ for a sequence $r_k \to 0$ then the singularity $0$ is removable, that is $g$ can be extended holomorphically the the disk. Indeed, consider $z \in D$, $z\ne 0$. Consider $r_k < |z|$. By the Cauchy formula we have 
$$ g(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\left( \int_{C_1} \frac{g(\zeta)}{ \zeta - z}-\int_{C_{r_k}} \frac{g(\zeta)}{ \zeta - z} \right)$$

Note that for $k\to \infty$ the term $\displaystyle\int_{C_{r_k}} \frac{g(\zeta)}{ \zeta - z}\to 0$ . Indeed, 
$$ \mid \int_{C_{r_k}} \frac{g(\zeta)}{ \zeta - z}\mid \,\le \, 2 \pi r_k\cdot  M_g(r_k) \cdot \frac{1}{|z| - r_k} $$

We conclude that

$$ g(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\cdot  \int_{C_1} \frac{g(\zeta)}{ \zeta - z} $$
for all $z$ in the pointed disk and therefore $g$ can be extended to the whole disk.

Comment: What did we show? What is the contradiction? Also, why does that second integral necessarily go to 0?

Comment: @JohnnyApple: I corrected a typo ( $\infty$ instead of $0$) , check again the statement that is shown, also the proof that the second integral $\to 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant I still don't see the contradiction.

Comment: Right, if $r^n M_f(r) \not \to 0$ then $z^n f(z)$ is holomorphic on the whole disk so $f(z)$ has a pole of order $\le n$ at $0$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29, so $0$ is a pole and not an essential singularity.

Comment: Oh of course. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnnyApple: No worries :-)